# Negative effects to ld: warning: section `.bss' type changed to PROGBITS

Tags: c, linker

I am sorry if this is too general of a question, but I haven't been able to find answers anywhere.  I am wondering if there is any negative effects of the bss section changed to PROGBITS. I have been getting this warning when I have been compiling programs under GCC 4.8.1. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

When the BSS section is changed to PROGBITS, the effect is that there are more NUL bytes (zeroes) in the output file. When .bss is NOBITS (what it should be), the linker puts information in the output file that tell the operating system to wipe a section of memory to all zeroes when the program is loaded. If it's PROGBITS, then this information only tells the operating system to load the memory area from the file, and that section of the file is filled with zeroes. So the only negative effect is that the output file is bigger.

Comment: What is the benefit for ld of PROGBITS over NOBITS?

Comment: The automatic type switch is triggered when a symbol is explicitly placed in a section that is assigned to .bss
Apparently this causes ld to enforce the existence of the entire bss section in the output file (i.e. using the PROGBITS type).

Comment: >> So the only negative effect is that the output file is bigger.



If you have no loader (ex. embedded systems), you may want to use PROGBITS for BSS.